# How to use KeyPressed in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I am working on my Java assignment. I have to create a virtual keyboard and my professor didn't teach us about KeyPressed and I am stuck for couple of days now.

My question is if I want the user to type something in the JTextFiled and want to change the background of the JButton to appear in different color whenever the user type any of the characters that are available on the keyboard, how can I do that?

For example, if the user hit the spacebar, I want the color of the spacebar on the frame to appear black and when the user releases the button, the color changes to it's original background color.

I know how to create JFrame, JButton, JLabel, and JPanel.

This is a simple code that I have created.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Assignment extends JFrame {

  private JButton jbtnSpace = new JButton(" ");
  private JPanel jpnl1 = new JPanel();

  private JTextArea txta = new JTextArea(10,62);

  public Assignment(){

  jpnl1.add(txta);

  jpnl1.add(jbtnSpace);

  this.add(jpnl1);

  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

        Assignment jfrm = new Assignment();

        jfrm.setTitle("Assignment");
        jfrm.setSize(710,440);
        jfrm.setVisible(true);
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    }

}
```

Please help. Thank you

Comment: Start by taking a look at [How to Write a Key Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html), then take a look at [Listening for Changes on a Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#doclisteners) for an alternative solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void jTextField1KeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                     

    int i=evt.getKeyChar();
    if(i==KeyEvent.VK_SPACE)     //or any Key Constant
    {
        //your code of changing the color
    }
}
```

I hope this helps. You must understand the working though, as described in one of the comments.